# New Text Field not showing up in a ToDoList type of App

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-layout

So I'm new to app dev and am developing a todolist type of app which can balance chemical equations. On clicking on a floating (+) button, a new textfield with a checkbox at it's left should pop up and data could be entered and saved. So, it involves an adapter class, model class, database handler class, AddNewTask class, all of which I'm adding. The problem is that on clicking the button, a textfield with a save button comes up with the keyboard to enter text but it does not "save" it on clicking the save button.

Adapter Class:

```
public class EqBalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EqBalAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<EqBalModel> EqBalList;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    public List<String> finalPrintval = new ArrayList<String>();


    public EqBalAdapter(DatabaseHandler db, MainActivity activity){
        this.db=db;
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.task_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
        db.openDatabase();
        EqBalModel item=EqBalList.get(position);
        holder.task.setText(item.getTask());
        holder.task.setChecked(toBoolean(item.getStatus()));
        holder.task.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    db.updateStatus(item.getId(),1);
                    finalPrintval.add(item.getTask());
                }else{
                    db.updateStatus(item.getId(),0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public int getItemCount(){
        return EqBalList.size();
    }
    private boolean toBoolean(int n){
        return n!=0;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<EqBalModel> EqBalList){
        this.EqBalList=EqBalList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public Context getContext(){
        return activity;
    }
    public void deleteItem(int position){
        EqBalModel item=EqBalList.get(position);
        db.deleteTask((item.getId()));
        EqBalList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
    public void editItem(int position){
        EqBalModel item=EqBalList.get(position);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id", item.getId());
        bundle.putString("task", item.getTask());
        AddNewTask fragment = new AddNewTask();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), AddNewTask.TAG);
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CheckBox task;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            task=view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        }
    }

}
```

Model class:

```
public class EqBalModel {
    private int id, status;
    private String task;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }
}
```

Database Handler class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION=1;
    private static final String NAME="EqualDatabase";
    private static final String TODO_TABLE = "todo";
    private static final String ID="id";
    private static final String TASK="task";
    private static final String STATUS="status";
    private static final String CREATE_TODO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TODO_TABLE + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                        + TASK + "TEXT, " + STATUS + " INTEGER)";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TODO_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        //DROP EXISTING TABLES
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TODO_TABLE);
        //CREATE TABLES AGAIN
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void openDatabase(){
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertTask(EqBalModel task){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TASK, task.getTask());
        cv.put(STATUS, 0);
        db.insert(TODO_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public List<EqBalModel> getAllTasks(){
        List<EqBalModel> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cur=null;
        db.beginTransaction();
        try{
            cur = db.query(TODO_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if(cur!= null){
                if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        EqBalModel task = new EqBalModel();
                        task.setId(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ID)));
                        task.setTask(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(TASK)));
                        task.setStatus(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(STATUS)));
                        taskList.add(task);

                    }while (cur.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        }finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            cur.close();
        }
        return taskList;
   }
   public void updateStatus(int id, int status){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(STATUS, status);
        db.update(TODO_TABLE, cv, ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
   }
   public void updateTask(int id, String task){
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TASK, task);
        db.update(TODO_TABLE, cv, ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
   }
   public void deleteTask(int id){
        db.delete(TODO_TABLE, ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
   }
}
```

AddNewTask class:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.Adapter.EqBalAdapter;
import com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.Model.EqBalModel;
import com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.Utils.DatabaseHandler;
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class AddNewTask extends BottomSheetDialogFragment{

    public static final String TAG = "ActionBottomDialog";
    private EditText newTaskTest;
    private Button newTaskSaveButton;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    EqAlgo obj = new EqAlgo();

    public static AddNewTask newInstance(){
        return new AddNewTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_task, container, false);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        newTaskTest=getView().findViewById(R.id.newTaskText);
        newTaskSaveButton=getView().findViewById(R.id.newTaskButton);

        db=new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        db.openDatabase();

        boolean isUpdate = false;
        final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            isUpdate=true;
            String task=bundle.getString("task");
            newTaskTest.setText(task);
            if(task.length()>0)
                newTaskSaveButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.teal));
        }
        newTaskTest.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.toString().equals(" ") || s.toString().equals("ERROR")){
                    newTaskSaveButton.setEnabled(false);
                    newTaskSaveButton.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    newTaskSaveButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    s.toString().equals("REFER TO HELP GUIDE");
                }else{
                    newTaskSaveButton.setEnabled(true);
                    newTaskSaveButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.teal));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().startsWith("Eq")){
                    String maineqtobeChck = (String) s.subSequence(2,s.length());
                    s.append(obj.equationBalance(maineqtobeChck));
                }
            }
        });
        boolean finalIsUpdate = isUpdate;
        newTaskSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = newTaskTest.getText().toString();
                Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(v, text, 5000);

                if(finalIsUpdate){
                    db.updateTask(bundle.getInt("id"), text);
                    mySnackbar.show();

                }else{
                    EqBalModel task = new EqBalModel();
                    task.setTask(text);
                    task.setStatus(0);
                }
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
        Activity activity=getActivity();
        if(activity instanceof DialogCloseListener){
            ((DialogCloseListener)activity).handleDialogClose(dialog);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity floating button code:

```
 db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        db.openDatabase();

        taskList = new ArrayList<>();

        taskRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.reacRecyclerView);
        taskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        tasksAdapter = new EqBalAdapter(db, this);
        taskRecyclerView.setAdapter(tasksAdapter);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new
                ItemTouchHelper(new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(tasksAdapter));
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(taskRecyclerView);

        taskList = db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.setTasks(taskList);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddNewTask.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), AddNewTask.TAG);
            }
```

The input has to be made in two ways: Either starting with Eq for an equation or normal text.
When typing with Eq, app closes with the following logcat error:

```
2021-03-05 17:02:45.128 31607-31607/com.example.chemicalequationbalancer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chemicalequationbalancer, PID: 31607
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.AddNewTask$1.afterTextChanged(AddNewTask.java:92)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9903)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:12741)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1273)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:506)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:36)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:863)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:636)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:401)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
2021-03-05 17:02:45.246 1196-3325/? E/Process: get_ion_cache_memory: Unable to open /d/ion/heaps/system
2021-03-05 17:02:45.267 1196-1322/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6510a0d com.example.chemicalequationbalancer/com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-03-05 17:02:45.268 1196-1322/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'e291db4 com.example.chemicalequationbalancer/com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-03-05 17:02:45.302 31963-31963/? E/.qualityprotec: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-03-05 17:02:45.320 31963-31963/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2021-03-05 17:02:45.363 20699-20724/? E/neodaemon: ERROR  elsaNotifyAppSwitch is NULL
2021-03-05 17:02:45.381 1196-4979/? E/OifaceUtil: Cannot connect to OifaceService
```

When typing normally, the app does not close but there is no field created after saving. The logcat says incompetent memory.

Please ask for any more files needed! Really Appreciated if you help. Thanks!

Comment: post logcat after you click the save button with a text

Comment: @MajidAli Sorry my laptop broke down, just got repaired. ive posted that